# I'm getting error while building the project in vue for ffmpeg.wasm

Tags: vue.js, npm, ffmpeg, build

Hi i'm getting below error when i build the project with **$npm run build** command

[image]

I'm using vuetify `"vuetify": "^2.4.0"` still because 3.0 is still in beta so i'm using `"vue": "^2.6.11",`

**Here is my `package.json`**

```
{
   ....
   "dependencies": {
      "@ffmpeg/core": "^0.11.5",
      "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg": "^0.11.0",
      "core-js": "^3.6.5",
      "vue": "^2.6.11",
      "vue-router": "^3.5.3",
      "vuetify": "^2.4.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
      "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
      "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
      "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
      "eslint": "^6.7.2",
      "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
      "sass": "~1.32.0",
      "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
      "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.5",
      "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
      "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "root": true,
      "env": {
        "node": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:vue/essential",
        "eslint:recommended"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "parser": "babel-eslint"
      },
      "rules": {}
    },
    "browserslist": [
      "> 1%",
      "last 2 versions",
      "not dead"
    ]
  }
```

**Note:** it was working fine with `"@ffmpeg/ffmpeg": "^0.10.1",` when i updated it to `"@ffmpeg/ffmpeg": "^0.11.0",` it is not working

in my `vue.config.js` there is nothing much , except `transpileDependencies`

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ]
}
```

**Here is i have uploaded my project** https://easyupload.io/rl9xyd [Download with high speed]

**Note:** i want to use `vuetify`

**Question:** i want to build with `"@ffmpeg/core": "^0.11.0", "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg": "^0.11.5"`  and `vuetify`

Please help me to resolve the error thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Vue version is irrelevant because ffmpeg is unaware of Vue. It's Vue CLI that could affect the way it works. Syntax error in the package means that it needs to be transpiled, it could be added to transpiledDependencies. The error shows that main entry point is in /src which may require additional configuration and time to be built. A prebuilt module could be imported instead, `@ffmpeg/ffmpeg/dist/ffmpeg.min.js`

Comment: @EstusFlask, Thanks for your valuable suggestion !! . i have tried both the ways 1) by adding `transpileDependencies: [ 'vuetify', '@ffmpeg/core', '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg' ]`   2)  by adding  at the caller like this `corePath: new URL("@ffmpeg/core/dist/ffmpeg-core.js",document.location).href
})` still getting similar error    this https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/vue-app project is compiling fine but for `vuetify` dependency i did not go with that . even my project is old and i'm maintaining that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that in ffmpeg 0.11, they changed how @ffmpeg/ffmpeg imports the core.  This is the commit that changed it https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/commit/ff9c27e3bfdfb94484502cd9d355781bdba10265.  Vue 2 uses Webpack 4 which isn't compatible with this change to use `import.meta.url`.  Webpack 5 supports it, and apparently there were loaders for Webpack 4 to work around it, but they seem to be dead now.

I think the easiest solution is to use the prebuilt version of @ffmpeg/ffmeg instead.  You can change your import in App.vue from

`import { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';`

to

`import { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg/dist/ffmpeg.min.js';`

to use the prebuilt.  That makes the demo build, but the demo doesn't seem to do anything, so can't verify that it works.

Comment: @eabengaluru Have you tried this?

Comment: I tried this and with 0.11.6 i'm getting `ReferenceError: self is not defined` on line1, character 194.

Answer (score -1):

When i tried to install i've got dependencies conflict:

[image: Dependencies conflicts]

so as it's an old Vue project start by updating them

When i read the boilerplate Vue project: [Boilerplate Ffmpeg](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/vue-app/blob/main/package.json)

i saw their version is `"@ffmpeg/ffmpeg": "^0.11.5",`

I think you mixed both  and used it in the `core` instead: [ffmpeg/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ffmpeg/core)

What you have to do:

1. the core version should be: `0.11.0`
2. @ffmpeg/ffmpeg should be `^0.11.5`

And after updating all of these i could get the build working perfectly:

[image: Build Working]

Here you have the `package.json` i have if the issue persist that means you have a problem with how you are using something but not the dependencies

```json
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@ffmpeg/core": "^0.11.0",
    "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg": "^0.11.5",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
```

Comment: ok i will try to build, if it is successful then i will accept your answer

Comment: Tell me if there is something else i can do for you :)

Comment: @SayfEddine with this packages `"@ffmpeg/core": "^0.11.0",
    "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg": "^0.11.5",` also same this is what I have posted.

Comment: @EaBengaluru this is not what you have posted look again what is inside your package.json

Comment: Did you copy paste the package.json ? Because the project I have build without any problem

Comment: whatever you have mentioned above same way my package.json is there without need for any changes

Comment: Mister read your package.json again pls because you inversed the core and the ffmpeg… you can open them in two editor and compare them